# MATLAB: Using "regexp" for filtering letters and digits

Tags: regex, matlab

It's a simple question, but I just can't deal with regexp and after couple hours of trying I'm hoping you can help me.

I have program a function that scans a string and starts specific operations depending on the cases and digits in the input-string.

First I scan the input via textscan, take it into a vector via {} and extract the size. Then I want to have in the first column the cases and in the second column the digits.

```
%split String spaces 
Zelle = textscan(trafostr, '%s');
%save in Vector
nZelle = Zelle{1,1};
[z s] = size(nZelle);

%set Startermatrix
nmatrix = eye(3);

for i=1:z;
    nString(i,1) = num2str(nZelle{i,1}, '%f');


nString(i,1) = num2str(nZelle{i,1}, '%f');
```

Comment: Could you please make up a small example of an input and the wanted output?

Comment: Sure, the Input should be like: trafostr = hu2 hv3 rt45 while the output is a combined transformation matrix.

Comment: Is the string part you're looking for always a two letter code? ('hu', 'hv', 'rt' etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to get something like this?

```
trafostr = 'hu2 hv3 rt45';

%split String spaces
Zelle = textscan(trafostr, '%s');
%save in Vector
nZelle = Zelle{1,1};
[z,s] = size(nZelle);

for i=1:z;
    Ouptput{i,1} = nZelle{i}( isletter(nZelle{i}) );
    Ouptput{i,2} = nZelle{i}( ~isletter(nZelle{i}) );
end



Ouptput = 
    'hu'    '2' 
    'hv'    '3' 
    'rt'    '45'
```